# MVC with web queries

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, nsurlconnection

I've written my first app that uses web data for building a custom view. While it is working, I can't help but think that maybe it isn't quite following the MVC concept (thought I'm not sure this plays into how Apple approves apps or not).

I have a single view controller with a custom view class that implements `drawRect`. Because the drawRect requires data from the web, it felt natural to do all the downloading within the custom view class itself.

But how is this usually done? I am guessing that the view controller should usually handle the downloading, and that the controller is the delegate for the async download so it can arrange views and such based on errors, etc. Instead, my custom view class is the delegate for handling the async, and that just seems poorly organized to me; but maybe it isn't?

If I were to instead use the View Controller for all the downloading, I suppose I would just set instance variables of the custom view to the results of the download, since the custom view needs the data to draw. Would that be a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't look at your source code as part of the App Store review process, so how you design your classes is up to you. However, you're right in thinking that in an MVC architecture, views don't fetch their own data, and in fact never have any knowledge of where the data they're presenting comes from. The controller layer acts as the bridge between views and model objects, so thats where the responsibility for fetching the data properly lies.

So I think you're on the right track: use an instance of a subclass of `UIViewController` to do obtain the data. From there, it's up to you to decide whether it makes more sense to 'push' or 'pull' the data into the UIView subclass you're designing.

In the push model, the controller sets instance variables of the view as necessary to present data. In the pull model, the view would typically send messages to the controller to request data prior to drawing. The typical pattern for this in iOS is to have the controller adopt a delegate protocol declared in the header for your custom view class. The view would then try to obtain data when needed by first checking to see whether its delegate implements the necessary methods, and then calling the methods if available.

Comment: I would be inclined to say that this job does not live in the controller but I'm open for debate as I am really not sure. I like to think of the `M` and `V` as swappable components around a fairly static `C`. If you place this logic in the `Model` then the `Controller` just asks for data to pass to the `View`. If we make the `Model` handle this then we can swap the backing source of the data (say we cache to local files or decide we want to get data from database) without effecting the `View` or `Controller`. This `Model` can now also be reused by multiple `Controllers`. Just my thoughts.

Comment: How would a model object know when to fetch itself?

Comment: The `Controller` tells it to. The controller would essentially create the model and say `myViewLabel = [model getLabelContent];` (simplified contrived example). The model object could be fetching from the web, a file, a sqlite ... it does not matter and the `controller` does not care it just wants to pass data to the view

Comment: So you're saying the model object would already exist, and then populate itself. I'm not sure I understand why the app would have an instance of this model class laying around before it was actually needed. Maybe a concrete example would help.

Comment: An example: You have a `JSONReader` `Model` that you pass a url to and it will fetch a JSON feed + return it as an `NSArray`. In your instance of `UITableViewController`, when it needs data it calls `JSONReader *jsonReader = [[JSONReader alloc] initWithURL:myURL];`. We then ask `JSONReader` to return an `NSArray` with `[jsonReader getData];`. Now if I want to reuse my `JSONReader` object with another class I can and I can change `JSONReader` for any class that responds to `getData` and returns an `NSArray` in the right format. Any clearer? It makes sense to me still, kind of :S

Comment: I think your understanding of what's meant by a model object is a little different than mine. A class named JSONReader whose role is to fetch data is a controller in my world. The objects it fetches would be the model objects.

Comment: Well I am thinking in terms of a model being the place for persisted data and business logic. In this case the fetched data is essentially persisted data. Using the controller to fetch data makes no sense to me as you would not be able to easily reuse that object anywhere else in your codebase. You are correct the `JSONReader` in my contrived example would most likely create many instances of a specific object. I thought one of the fundamental rules of MVC was the controller does not create data.

Comment: In `session 116 - Model-View-Controller for iPhone OS` dev centre 2010 videos about 9:00 mins in. The presenter (Ken Kocienda) says Models are all about Data/Algorithms/Networking, Controllers are all about coordination/delegation and odd jobs.

Comment: I love this discussion, thank you. I am taking away two points: 1) it is easier to push data from a controller than it is for a custom view to pull it. 2) web queries do not belong in the custom view. As to where the queries go, i think it makes most sense in the MVC architecture to have a separate class that is the model and handles the downloads. Though i would think that you would need the controller as the nsurl connection delegate to handle errors, alert views, etc. Right?

Comment: Because when a model finishes downloading, its delegate needs to know. If that delegate is "self" then you are stuck having to somehow push data to the controller, rather than just have the controller manage the results of the web query directly.

Comment: Any data that is part of the persistent state of the application (whether that persistent state is stored in files or databases) should reside in the model objects **once the data is loaded into the application**. [Emphasis added]  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1

Comment: The snippet you have provided has been read out of context it refers to an applications persistant data being loaded into models from local sources (`whether that persistent state is stored in files or databases`), when it says `once the data is loaded into the application` it is referring to loading from disk. My issue is that the viewController has to know an awful lot about how that data is received e.g. constructing the url, negotiating any authentication and then abstracting the response. That sounds like an awful lot of business logic for a controller to have.

Comment: Constructing a URL is not business logic. Business logic is logic that has to do with the domain being modeled, for example determining the sales tax rate or whether a discount applies for a given invoice.